# Could SharePoint 2013 Survey Hide "See Results"?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, survey

I have a survey in SharePoint 2013 that I have a question about.

My original goal was to allow the user to take a survey, but not let them see the responses of ANY users (neither themselves nor others). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Target Audience to achieve it.

The steps for your reference:
1. Go to your survey List, then switch to **All Responses** view
2. Edit **All Responses** view page, and edit the list web part.
3. In Advanced section, set Target Audience to a SharePoint Group which contains the users who could see all responses.
4. Same Steps for **Graphical Summary** view
[image]

Then Users who are not in the SharePoint Group will not see all responses .

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible OOTB. You can hide the list from users and keep answer survey link on a page.